# Show that $\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx$ is at least $2\sqrt{2}$ without evaluating the integral

Tags: calculus, integration, recreational-mathematics

Problem: Show that $\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx$ is at least $2\sqrt{2}$ without evaluating the integral

By breaking the integral into two parts, and with some substitution of variables, I was able to obtain:

$\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{(x-1)^2+1}+\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}\,dx$

Then I took the derivative of the integrand (on the right side of above equation) with respect to $x$ and was able to show through much algebra that it was greater than $0$ for $0<x<1$.

From this I concluded that the integrand is increasing over the interval $(0,1)$ and therefore the integrand is at least $2\sqrt{2}$
(i.e., the value of the integrand at $x=0$) over the interval $[0,1]$, and therefore:

$\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx \geq 2\sqrt{2}$

This seems sound, but I wonder if there is some other observation to be made that would provide a simpler or more elegant solution.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: this is equivalent to the integrand being, on average on the integration range, at least what it is at the range's midpoint. In other words, you can use Jensen's inequality.

Comment: Never heard of Jensen's inequality, but I will know go read about it. Thank you!

Comment: Upon review of the Jensen's inequality, it appears that if the integrand is convex then it is just a simple application of the inequality...and maybe a few algebra steps. Cool! Thanks again!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The arc length of the graph of $\frac12t^2$ on $0\le t\le x$ is
$$\int_0^x\sqrt{t^2+1}\,dt$$
and is longer than the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(x,x^2/2)$. When $x=2$ this becomes $\int_0^2\sqrt{t^2+1}\,dt\ge\sqrt{2^2+2^2}=2\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 5):

Since $y''=(x^2+1)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\geq 0$, the graph is concave-up.

The tangent line of the curve at $P(1,\sqrt{2})$ is $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and it cuts the $y$-axis at $A(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ and the line $y=2$ at $B(2,\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}})$.

The area of the trapezoid $O(0,0), A(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}), B(2,\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}), C(2,0)$, is equal to $\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}}{2}\times 2=2\sqrt{2}$.

Since graph is concave-up, the area under the curve is greater than the area of this trapezoid.

Answer (score 4):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality  $$\int\limits_0^2\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx\ge \int\limits_0^2{x\cdot 1+1\cdot 1\over \sqrt{2}}\,dx=2\sqrt{2}$$